# How to remove a full directory via Debian commandline?

Tags: bash, rm

I am trying to make a bash install script.  One of the tasks it has to do is to remove a certain full directory if it is present.  I tried `rmdir [location of directory]` but it gives an error saying the directory is "not empty, so not removed". I couldn't find anything online about it.  That is, I read some articles with no success. How can I make it remove the directory properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rmdir only works if the given directory is empty. Directly from the rmdir man page:

"*The rmdir utility removes the directory entry specified by each directory argument, provided it is empty*."

You should probably be using:

```
$ rm -rf your_directory
```

The **-r** essentially means to recursively remove all files and dirs.

The **-f** means to remove files without prompting you and ignores file permissions.

Comment: Please, only for completude, explain what -r and what -f does